# Knockout Drag & Drop can't find the "drop zone" after removing all the child elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js, drag-and-drop

With the help of Ryan Niemeyer's blog post http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html I have written code that allows dragging and dropping between nested observablearrays.  The problem I'm facing is when I remove all items under "Encounter", and want to return an item, it can't find the container or drop area to properly work.  It will drop as if it does work, but if you look at the JSON output, you'll see that it does not properly update.  The same problem exists when I remove all encounters, and try to move one encounter back... it doesn't find it's "drop zone".  I'm hoping it is something trivial and appreciate the help.

I have a demo of it here http://plnkr.co/edit/n7IGItDOYTzCSfDHlwJS?p=preview

Here is the script:

```
 $(function() {

 //control visibility, give element focus, and select the contents (in order)
 ko.bindingHandlers.visibleAndSelect = {
 update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
   ko.bindingHandlers.visible.update(element, valueAccessor);
   if (valueAccessor()) {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $(element).find("input").focus().select();
     }, 0); //new encounters are not in DOM yet
   }
  }
 };

 var Dataset = function(name) {
 var self = this;
 self.dName = name;
 self.type = "Dataset";
 };

 // Encounter construction
 var Encounter = function(name, dss) {
 var self = this;
 self.name = name;
 self.datasets = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.type = "Encounter";

 $.each(dss, function(i, p) {
   self.datasets.push(new Dataset(p.dName));
 });
};

 // Patient construction
 var Patient = function(id, encounters) {
 var self = this;
 self.id = ko.observable(id);
 self.encounters = ko.observableArray([]);

 $.each(encounters, function(i, p) {
   self.encounters.push(new Encounter(p.name, p.Datasets));
 });
 };


  my.vm = {

 selectedItem: ko.observable(),
 patients: ko.observableArray([]),
 targetPatients: ko.observableArray([]), 


 isSelected: function(selectedItem) {
   return selectedItem === this.selectedItem();
 },




 isDropSpotMatch: function(arg) {
    //if (!my.vm.isSourceEncounterSelected && !my.vm.isTargetEncounterSelected)  {
    //    arg.cancelDrop = true;
    //}
    //var t = ko.toJSON(arg);
    //console.log(arg);
    //alert(ko.toJSON(arg.sourceParent()[0])); 
    console.log(arg.sourceParent()[0]);
    console.log(arg.targetParent()[0]);

    if (arg.sourceParent()[0].type != arg.targetParent()[0].type){

      arg.cancelDrop = true;  
    }


 },

clearItem: function(data, event) {
    if (data === self.selectedItem()) {
        my.vm.selectedItem(null);                
    }

    if (data.name() === "") {
       my.vm.patients.remove(data);   
       my.vm.targetPatients.remove(data);
    }
},

 // loading the observable array with sample data
 load: function() { 
   $.each(my.sourceData.data.Patients, function(i, p) {
     my.vm.patients.push(new Patient(p.Id, p.Encounters));
   });

    $.each(my.targetData.data.Patients, function(i, p) {
     my.vm.targetPatients.push(new Patient(p.Id, p.Encounters));
   });

 }

};

ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.beforeMove = my.vm.isDropSpotMatch;
//ko.bindingHandlers.sortable.afterMove = my.vm.isDropSpotMatch;
my.vm.load();
ko.applyBindings(my.vm);
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<script data-require="knockout@*" data-semver="3.0.0"   src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="knockout-sortable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="data.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="page">
<div id="main">
  <div class="showroom">
  <table>
       <tr>
         <td>
           <span data-bind="sortable: { template: 'taskTmpl', data: patients }"></span>      
         </td>
         <td>
           <span data-bind="sortable: { template: 'taskTmpl', data: targetPatients }">  </span>      
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     <script id="taskTmpl" type="text/html">
      <ul data-bind="sortable: encounters">
      <div class="container"><div class="item">
        <li>
        <div class="encounterItem">
         <span data-bind="visible: !$root.isSelected($data)">
            <a href="#" data-bind="text: name, click: $root.selectedSourceEncounter">  </a>
        </span>
        <span data-bind="visibleAndSelect: $root.isSelected($data)">
            <input data-bind="value: name, event: { blur: $root.clearItem }" />
        </span>  
        </div>
        </div>
         <ul data-bind="sortable: datasets">
                <li>
                  <div class="datasetItem">
                    <span data-bind="visible: !$root.isSelected($data)"> 
                  <a href="#" data-bind="text: dName, click:    $root.selectedSourceEncounter"></a>
                </span>
                    <span data-bind="visibleAndSelect: $root.isSelected($data)">
                  <input data-bind="value: dName, event: { blur: $root.clearItem }" />
                </span>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div></script>

  <div>
      JSON OUTPUT
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>

    </div>       

  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the css:

```
.container {
background-color: #BBB;
}

.datasetItem {
background-color: #BBB;
cursor: move;
text-align: left;
width: 100px;

}

.encounterItem {
background-color: #BBB;
cursor: move;
text-align: left;
width: 100px;

}

.encounterItem input {
width: 40px;
}

.datasetItem input {
width: 40px;
}

.ko_container {
    width: 255px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: #ADDA;
}
```

And finally my namespace and dummy data:

```
var my = my || { }; //my namespace
my.dataservice = (function (my) {
"use strict";
var getPatients = function () {
    return my.sampleData;
};
return {
    getPatient: getPatients
};
})(my);

my.sourceData = (function (my) {    
"use strict";
var data = { Patients: [
                    { "Id": "1stId", "Encounters": [ { "name": "1stEncounter", "Datasets": [ { "dName": "1stDataset"}  ] }, { "name": "2ndEncounter", "Datasets": [ {  "dName": "2ndDataset"}  ] } ]  }

]
};
return {
    data: data
};
})(my);

my.targetData = (function (my) {    
"use strict";
var data = { Patients: [
                    { "Id": "T1stId", "Encounters": [ { "name": "21stEncounter",  "Datasets": [ { "dName": "21stDataset"}  ] }, { "name": "22ndEncounter", "Datasets": [ {  "dName": "22ndDataset"}  ] } ]  }

]
};
return {
    data: data
};
})(my);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is silly, but add a minimum height to the list  container.

Comment: That is what I usually do for sortables (min-height). There is an issue logged that I am hoping to address at some point to allow for a templated "empty" area: https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable/issues/77.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I will mess with my css/html to see if I can make this happen.

Comment: Following the hint that Matthew gave, and the follow up by the knockout god Ryan himself, I was able to find the fix.  I set the min-height on the ui-sortable in css.